# Counting columns in group in Pivot table

Tags: excel, count, pivot, pivot-table, grouping

Is it possible to somehow count the amount of columns in a specific group in a pivot table ?

I have a Pivot table with a dynamic range of columns, and I would like to get the amount of columns in a specific Column

[image]

I have the 2 groups `2022` and `2023` but I don't know how many number of columns/months there are in the "last" group .. that I would like to know

I googled and googled and everything I find is how to sum/count the data of the different columns, and not getting the `header` data of the pivot table group.

Comment: Why can't you just add your values to the Pivot Table a second time and change the aggregation from *Sum of* to *Count of*? If that doesn't work, suggest you post some copiable sample data (not a picture) with expected result.

Comment: wouldn't that still just count the amount of occurences in the pivottable, or do I misunderstand your suggestion ?

But is it possible to count the amount of columns in a group ?

Comment: Ah, yes, apologies, I understand what you mean now. I think the only way to achieve this would be to add your table to the Data Model and use a measure within Power Pivot.

Comment: As far as i Know, you cannot do this in your actual Pivot Table. You would need to add an extra column with this calculus in your source data and then add it to a new Pivot Table